How to hide connect / create operations on nested input types in prisma generated by prisma-nestjs-graphql
I'm currently setting up a project using NestJS with GraphQL and Prisma. I am using prisma-nestjs-graphql to generate the input types for my entities. However I have coma across this issue where I found that it generates the graphql input types for every entity with connect, connect or create for sub entities.
my nestjs graphql config
schema.prisma
generator nestgraphql {
  provider = "node node_modules/prisma-nestjs-graphql"
  output   = "../src/@generated"
}

generate input
export class UserCreateNestedManyWithoutArticlesInput {
    @Field(() => [UserCreateWithoutArticlesInput], { nullable: true })
    create?: Array<UserCreateWithoutArticlesInput>;

    @Field(() => [UserCreateOrConnectWithoutArticlesInput], { nullable: true })
    connectOrCreate?: Array<UserCreateOrConnectWithoutArticlesInput>;

    @Field(() => UserCreateManyArticlesInputEnvelope, { nullable: true })
    createMany?: UserCreateManyArticlesInputEnvelope;

    @Field(() => [UserWhereUniqueInput], { nullable: true })
    connect?: Array<UserWhereUniqueInput>;
}

So I am wondering is there a way to hide all create and connectOrCreate for sub entities. I looked up the documentation and so far I found the only way to do this is by adding decorator to generator like this
decorate_3_type = "*CreateNestedOneWithoutUserInput"
decorate_3_field = "!(create)"
decorate_3_name = "HideField"
decorate_3_from = "@nestjs/graphql"
decorate_3_arguments = "[]"

this works and hides create on this specific input. But tts very verbose and would soon get messy and i want to disable it on input types for most of my graphql entities. I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?
Thank you reading!
